# EC based password authenticated key exchange protocol

Tags: elliptic-curves, authentication, key-exchange, pake

I would like to know:

1. What is the currently best (efficiency and security wise) known EC based password authenticated key exchange protocol?
   (i.e. is there any EC based protocol may be similar to DH based SRP protocol)
2. What is the certicom's patent number/title of elliptic curve Point Compression? (I have searched net but I couldn't find)
3. In EC based user authentication protocol, how is user ID is sent?
   (i.e. sent in pain text or encrypted with RSA public key of server and then EC based key exchange is performed)

Comment: concerning 1 and 3: you might want to take a look at [TLS with pre-shared keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-PSK) (which could be derived using PBKDFs if high-entropy is required). [ECDHE_PSK-RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5489) [AES-GCM-SHA2-RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5489)